# Parsing a JSON string while preserving the original order of keys

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON string:

```
[{
    "Date": "1",
    "Time": "2007-10-01",
    "Tag": "test",
    "JetSpeed": "note",
    "HeadTemp": "200.00",
    "FaultList": "10.00;"
}, {
    "Date": "2",
    "Time": "2007-10-02",
    "Tag": "test2",
    "JetSpeed": "note2",
    "HeadTemp": "300.00",
    "FaultList": "20.00;"
}, {
    "Date": "3",
    "Time": "2007-09-01",
    "Tag": "test3",
    "JetSpeed": "note3",
    "HeadTemp": "400.00",
    "FaultList": "30.00;"
}]
```

I'm attempting to use this code to get the JSON data, so I can use it:

```
var logtabledata = $.parseJSON(data.Parameters);
// When I use this gives me array objects
```

For example, if you access `logtabledata[0]`, the first key will be `Date`, with a value of 1. The next key is `FaultList` value is 10.00, but I need the next key to be `Time` instead.

It arranges the data in sorted order, but I need to preserve the original order of the keys. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by *CD..*, an object is an unordered collection of properties.

You have at least two options:

- you can use arrays instead of objects
- you can iterate over the array and print/use the properties from the objects in chosen order easily by using their names.

  ```
  var a = $.parseJSON(data.Parameters);

  for (var i = 0, ilen = a.length; i < ilen; i += 1) {
      console.log(a[i].Date);
      console.log(a[i].FaultList);
      // etc
  }
  ```

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to use an array, and not an object if you want to preserve order:

> An object is a member of the type Object. **It is an unordered
>   collection of properties** each of which contains a primitive value,
>   object, or function.

---

Alternatively, you can also create a array of the keys for order purpose:

For example:

```
var order =  ['Date', 'Time', 'Tag', 'JetSpeed', 'HeadTemp', 'FaultList'];

logtabledata.forEach(function (item) {
   order.forEach(function (key) {
        console.log(item[key]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but my requirement is i need to pass an array of objects to data: logtabledata,colNames: arr,colModel: colModel, to Jqgrid so i need to preserve the order it comes and logtabledata should be of array type only how shall i do this.if i iterate and use array it will be sorted order.so how to preserve order? atleast date and time should be displayed first

Comment: @cmj: sounds like your might be missing something regarding the jqgrid options. Maybe try asking a new question focusing your jqgrid code.